# how to work with code when web driver is open

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pyqt5

ok; I wrote a code and use python selenium and then with pyqt5 made it graphical.
but when I push the button start webdriver opened and I can't access to my windows's code any more, It got frozen , but I should input some valuable or click on some button as the code running.
what should I do ?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem before. My solution was to use the time.sleep(duration) when the web driver opened the Window. For your specific situation, I think that you can use javascript on the page to check the user input is complete or not. Once the input fields are filled then trigger the process behind.

Comment: I try that but does't work.
I designed  a pause button but I can't click on it ;

Answer (score 0):

What I did was using a Process, so it would seperate the GUI-Loop and everything what is being done by selenium in a Process. By doing so you'll be able to use your GUI parallel to running Selenium in the Background by your process.

Comment: how I can send it to background ?

Comment: I do it with a process e.g. `self.platformProcess = mp.Process(target=AutomateSpreadshirt, args=(self.controller.printQueue, self.controller.closeQueue, ".com"), kwargs={"csv":csv})` And all the things you automate with selenium come in the function you process.